# THREE.js enormous memory overhead when loading mesh from server

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a mesh on server side as json. I then send JSON request to server and recieve rather gigantic json (55M), which I then parse and fill up an instance of `THREE.Geometry`.

Before I load the mesh, memory consumption of Firefox is 200M, when the operation is complete, the mesh is loaded and displayed on the canvas, the consuption skyrockets to 2G.

Now using [this little function](https://gist.github.com/zensh/4975495), I'm calculating the sizes of all objects, that participate in loading and displaying the mesh and I get the following:

- JSON string recieved from server: 108M
- parsed JSON object: 48M
- geometry object: 176M

Now all that totals up to 332M of memory consumption, while FF has eaten up to 1.8G, which is an overhead of almost 1.5G.

So the question is, where does all this overhead come from and how can I avoid it?

Comment: That must be a very big mesh you are using... Maybe some details on the actual data could be useful to this question?

Comment: Yep, it's big. A bit more than 1 mil tris, 500k+ verts. As I said, actual data is stored in 55M json, I'm getting via AJAX, and then building actual THREE.js geometry.

Comment: Maybe you should consider using `BufferGeometry` instead of `Geometry`. It might save you some memory.

Comment: Yep, tried that, but I need raycasting, so I need faces.

Comment: I think raycasting on buffer geometries is supported in the latest version of three.js